# Bootstrap centering div image and text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make like a card, I've made it with a div, with an image and a text, and I don't know how to center them vertically. This is how my card looks:

[image]

and this is how it should look:

[image]

This is the code of the div:

```
            <div class="panel mx-auto col align-items-center">
              <img class="atajo-content" :src="shortcut.img" height="83" />
              <p class="pt-1 card-name text-wrap">{{ shortcut.name }}</p>
            </div>
```

And I just couldn't center the icon with the font. I've tested it with almost all combinations of bootstrap and I cannot understand what happens.

Comment: Please update the code with the required library and code to show the output. You can use Codesandbox or Stackblitz for it.

Comment: You can use the `text-center` class on your div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. If you want your content to be vertically center, then you need to give specific height to the parent `.main-content`. Here we have used flex utility classes to center the content as per your requirement.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/n39zby6g/

```css
.main-content {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="main-content d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="panel">
    <img class="atajo-content" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" height="83" />
    <p class="pt-1 card-name text-wrap">{{ shortcut.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Yudiz!!

Comment: We are glad that our solution helped you... :)